# Can i create a JNI call to Boost c++ fiber called from Java?

Tags: java, c++, boost, java-native-interface

I have a c++ custom lib in my java project. This custom c++ lib is using fibers (boost c++ library). Can i call a c++ fiber from java?
Theretically fiber works inside the VM thread even if VM dont know it. So all might be ok but maybe there is some thing that i know about VM design, not expected in this usage?  (Attention please it is not a normal c++ call , it is using fiber framework inside C++ , so TLS in c++ could conflict java maybe? the thread context switch is the same?)

Answer (score 0):

**Can i call a c++ fiber from java?**

Yes, You can call C++ Library in Java . You can use **Java Native Interface (JNI)** in order to call C++ modules into java.

So you will have to write wrapper library to access built in library in C++ if required.
So Java code will connect to Wrapper C++ Library using JNI and Wrapper Library will connect to fibre library of C++.

Please refer following [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html) to understand the JNI call's.

Comment: Sorry but the question was another . I know JNI. c++Fiber could affect directly the VM internals .

Comment: After a test about porting c++ boost fiber in java ... i can tell you , it doesnt  work (it works just if the c++ fiber is executing c++ code else there is a stackoverflow)  , so the response above is wrong. This experiment has a important effect in the future interoperability . Java it will not be more interoperable with c++ . The fibers must be implemented at os kernel level for be transparent at higher levels

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings.